# $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}=0$ $\implies f=$ constant.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity, contest-math

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with the property that

$$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \dfrac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}=0$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Are you asking that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: for a given $h$ one has
$${f(x + h) - f(x) \over h} = {f(x + h) - f(x + h/2) \over h} + {f(x + h/2) - f(x + h/4) \over h} + ....$$
$$=  {1 \over 2}{f(x + h) - f(x + h/2) \over h/2} + {1 \over 4}{f(x + h/2) - f(x + h/4) \over h/4 } + ....$$
You actually need continuity of $f(x)$ already for the above. Now take limits as $h$ goes to zero in the above carefully and conclude ${\displaystyle \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} {f(x + h) - f(x) \over h}} $ is always exists and is equal to zero. Then use this to show $f$ is constant.

Comment: The partial sums are ${\displaystyle {f(x + h) - f(x + {h \over 2^n}) \over h}}$. By continuity of $f$ this converges to ${\displaystyle {f(x+h) - f(x) \over h}}$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: how I finish? Because not necessarily $\lim \sum a_i = \sum \lim a_i $

Comment: @leticia Show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, then if $h$ is small enough the $n$th term is of absolute value $< {\epsilon \over 2^n}$

Comment: There's only a minor gap: It only shows that $\lim_{h\to0^+}(f(x+h)-f(x))/h=0$, not $f'(x)=0$. But in this weaker condition $f$ is also a constant (It's known that if the Dini derivative $D^+f\ge0$ everywhere, then $f$ is nondecreasing).

Comment: @FrankScience Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @Zarrax of course! Nice solution :) thank you.

Comment: For a proof of the last part, see the "Application" part of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability

Comment: @FrankScience, I think I just found my mistake now. Thanks, I was too hasty.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$.
Assume that there exist $x$ such that $f(x)$ is positive. Consider $h$ so small so that $f(x+2h)$ is positive  Then since $f$ is continuous there exist $h>0$ such that $f(x+h) < f(x)+\varepsilon$
Then $$f(x+2h)-f(x+h)>f(x+2h)-f(x)-\varepsilon$$
So if we take the limit as h tends to zero we get
$$\lim_{h\to0} (f(x+2h)-f(x+h)-(f(x+2h)-f(x)))< \varepsilon$$ but since that is true for all $\varepsilon>0$ it must be that in fact $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}h=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}h$$ and by the property we are given by the problem we conclude that the latter is equal to zero therefore by definition of differentiability $f$ has derivative equal to zero at $x$. But $x$ is  just an arbitrary  point with positive $f(x)$. By continuity of $f$ there exist a neighborhood of points around x where we have $f(\text{of those points})>0$ therefore this neighborhood of points has derivative equal to zero at any point and therefore $f$ is constant in that neighborhood so lets say is equal to $c$. Now we consider the closure of this neighborhood, the two points in the closure will have $f(\text{closure points})=c$ by continuity of $f$ and since $c>0$ there exist another neighborhoods with $f(\text{of points})>0$ so they are also constant. Continuing like that we see $f$ is constant.
If no point $x$ such that $f(x)>0$ exist but there exist only $x$ such that $f(x)<0$ with a similar argument proof that $f$ is constant (consider $-f(x)$ and show it is constant)
if none of the two cases exist then $f$ is the zero function which is constant.

Comment: user142775: I have tried to improve readability of your post by adding TeX. Please, edit the post further if needed. For example where you write $\lim$ do you mean $\lim\limits_{h\to0}$? Is $(f(x+2h)-f(x)/h)$ a typo and should it be $(f(x+2h)-f(x))/h$?) For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).